# Second countable profinite space

Tags: profinite-groups

The [Corollary 1.1.13 in my text book](https://books.google.it/books?id=u8GWrhdhA2QC&pg=PA11&dq=Profinite+Groups+1.1.13&hl=it&sa=X&ei=kOXVVID4HMTgaMqVgNgP&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Profinite%20Groups%201.1.13&f=false) is the following statement.

> $\textbf{Corollary 1.1.13}$ A profinite space $X$ is second countable if and only if
>
> $$X\cong \varprojlim_{i\in I}X_i$$
>
> where $(I,\leq)$ is a countable totally ordered set and each $X_i$ is finite discrete space.

And the proof starts as follows:

> **Proof**
>
> Suppose $X$ is profinite and second countable. Consider the set $\mathcal{R}$ of all open equivalence relations on $X$. For $R\in \mathcal{R}$, $xR$ is a finite union of basic open set. Hence $\mathcal{R}$ is countable.

But I can't understand why is $xR$ a finite union of basic open set and why does it imply $\mathcal{R}$ countable.

Please tell me if you know.

Comment: The equivalence classes of any one of your equivalence relations form an open cover of $X$, right? Then use compactness (in the form of profiniteness) to get a finite subcover with basic open sets. So you can identify each $R$ with a finite subset of your basis.  There are only countably many finite subsets of a countable set, so $\mathcal R$ is countable.

Comment: How can I identify each $R$ with a finite subset of the basis? I think sometimes some $xR$ cannot be made by finite union. Is this impossible?